# Fixed number of touches on the screen in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

Is it possible to limit the simultaneous tap on the screen to only two taps? Not through Input.touchCount, but so that the screen simply does not respond to new clicks if there are already two fingers on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not do `if(Input.touchCount == 2) return;` ?

Comment: I keep track of touches on the screen in Update and use the information for the joystick and camera rotation, so under this condition they will simply stop being work

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem in a bit more detail? because Working with Touches in Unity is quite complicated. you can not just check the total counts and take the value from the first two touches based on the index. Because in the touch array, the index of all touche is changing.

Comment: I use two joysticks. One to move and the other to rotate the camera. I was able to set both joysticks to work correctly with two fingers, but if testing with more than two fingers on the screen, then additional configuration is required. I thought maybe there is a setting with which you can only track two clicks, but no more.